# Scaling the QGraphicsScene to fill whole QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have found a few fixes for this issue, but none of seemed to be sufficient. I have a `QGraphicsView` displaying a `QGraphicsScene`. What I want to do is to scale the scene in order to fill the whole view. Also I want it to scale dynamically when the user will be resizing the window displaying the view. Is such a thing possible? If so I'd be glad if you could give me a short example on how should it be implemented. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your custom class which inherits from QGraphicsView.  You should reimplement resizeEvent( QResizeEvent *event ) in your custom QGraphicsView like:

```
void MyView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

    fitInView(0, 0, 500, 500,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

This way the view will always display the whole scene. I.e. if the window size is changed and the graphicsView is resized, The scene gets scaled and you can see everything appropriately.

Comment: Just to add for people having this problem in the future:
    "fitInView(sceneRect, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);"
seems to be a much better choice.